# Is using your website as a username spam or self promotion?

Tags: support, spam, display-names

People are finding variety of ways to self-promote; the latest being the use of website's name as a username.

I'm talking about this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470953/www-sblog-in).

Is it right to do that?

Comment: The most common complaint about self-promotion is *undisclosed* self-promotion using links in otherwise usable answers.  That user's name might be self-promotion, but it's sure as hell not *undisclosed*, and I don't see any actual links to the site outside of the one on the profile page...

Answer (score 7):

This issue [has been addressed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100860/are-user-names-that-represent-domains-allowed) on Meta Stack Exchange and is generally found not to be an issue. It is an identity you choose for yourself and not part of the actual content of the site. Or as [Robert Cataino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) says [in the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100922/161198):

> The identity you choose is a personal thing. If someone wanted to be called (for example) "Ubuntu Fanboi", we wouldn't be having this conversation. So is a username like "AskUbuntu.com" really all that different? It's not indiscriminate advertising... it's a username; and it's not a part of the information content of this site. In short, there is no "spam" to a username.

So in summary, that's just fine.

Comment: I don't entirely agree. What would SO do if somebody took the username adobe.com and Adobe complained about possible Trademark infringement? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253396/what-is-the-so-policy-regarding-misleading-usernames

Comment: In that situation I would assume the impersonation clause would kick in @BrunoLowagie. But for that to happen it would either have to be obvious that's the case, or the other party would have to actually complain. It is however not a case of self-promotion or spam, but a different issue altogether.

Comment: I complained to github about https://github.com/itextsharper/ because the username itextsharper is a clear reference to iTextSharp, but the user itextsharper isn't known by anyone at the iText companies. GitHub didn't take action. I wonder what SO would do.

Comment: That would be something for them to answer. I have a guess, but that's not really relevant. And in that case we're no longer talking self-promotion/spam, so it's not really relevant to the topic under discussion here.

Comment: No, not to this discussion, but your reference to Ubuntu triggered it.

Comment: Sure, and that's a good discussion to have @BrunoLowagie. :)