# What is the SO policy regarding misleading usernames?

Tags: discussion, users

I've just read the question [Is using your website as a username spam or self promotion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253392/is-this-considered-as-spam-or-self-promotion) asking if it's OK for a user to choose a user name that refers to his product.

I agree with the comment:

> The most common complaint about self-promotion is undisclosed
>   self-promotion using links in otherwise usable answers. That user's
>   name might be self-promotion, but it's sure as hell not undisclosed,

Personally, I've added an avatar that clearly shows that I'm the author of a specific software library.

However, I want to know what you think about misleading usernames. Suppose that I have a trademarked product named *123abc* and somebody else creates a user name that refers to *123abc* in an unambiguous way. What can I do to make sure that users of *123abc* don't confuse that person with somebody who is affiliated with *123abc*?

I've had the experience of a developer saying *"I've asked somebody at your company a question, and the answer I received was all wrong."* After investigating who had answered that question, it turned out to be somebody who wasn't related to our company in any way.

I don't agree with the answer:

> The identity you choose is a personal thing. If someone wanted to be called (for example) "Ubuntu Fanboi", we wouldn't be having this conversation. So is a username like "AskUbuntu.com" really all that different? It's not indiscriminate advertising... it's a username; and it's not a part of the information content of this site. In short, there is no "spam" to a username.

What would SO do if somebody took the username `Adobe.com` and Adobe complained that this user is in no way affiliated with Adobe?

Comment: The legal point is that Trademark owners are supposed to take action against those violating your Trademark. If they don't, their Trademark can be taken away. Unfortunately, some instances don't really care about Trademarks (Github) and others make it very difficult for you to enforce it (it took me weeks and a lawyer before I could claim a Twitter account from somebody who posted non sense). Hence the question: what's the policy on SO?

Comment: I know that impersonation or a false identity is not tolerated (See the "restrictions" section in the [TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal)). I would assume that extends to entities other than persons as well. But let's see.

Comment: I Googled `site:stackoverflow.com Trademark` and I found the page about the TM owned by StackExchange: http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance However, I didn't find a page about other Trademarks.

Comment: If you have a practical concern regarding users violating a trademark of yours, you can always contact the team using the "contact us" link at the bottom of the website.

Comment: Corporations [are people](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2h8ujX6T0A) in the US @Bart [:-(](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood), so, it should apply equally.

Comment: So is [Soylent Green](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1445291/soylentgreen) @Ben ...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37942/policy-on-display-names might be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Bart: The wording of the TOS only appears to prohibit impersonating another specific person. That being said, it's certainly bad form to use a name that suggests that you're associated with something you aren't (e.g, a company or web site), and I feel like it **should** probably be made part of policy.

Comment: @duskwuff I am not a lawyer, so I don't know what is included in an "identity".

Comment: @Bart: The bits I'm looking at are in §4 ("impersonate another person") and §7 ("select or use as a profile name a name of another person with the intent to impersonate that person"). The way I'm reading it, those seem to only cover impersonating a *specific* person, and wouldn't cover, say "An Apple Employee" or "github.com", as neither one is sufficiently specific.

Comment: There is *"Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to [...] create a false identity ..."* @duskwuff